# AWS: How to create auto tags for resources created by a specific group

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have a specific AWS group which has the policy `EC2FullAccess`. 
Now I want that resources of this group (ec2 instances) are auto tagged with "team A" and that this group can only use their fullAccess rights on the resources tagged with "team A". (so they can't delete other EC2 instances with a different tag). Is this possible?

I'm not using cloudformation to setup this group/grole at the moment, but will translate it to cfn in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AWS Answers provides the answer [here](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/iam-policy-tags-restrict/).

Here's their longest policy. It provides for a more complex policy than you need, but should serve as a good example for you - it should be fairly trivial to work it out from here.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowToDescribeAll",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:Describe*"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AllowRunInstances",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "ec2:RunInstances",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:ec2:*::image/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:*::snapshot/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:subnet/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:network-interface/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:security-group/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:key-pair/*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AllowRunInstancesWithRestrictions",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:CreateVolume",
                "ec2:RunInstances"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:volume/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:instance/*"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "aws:RequestTag/key1": "value1",
                    "aws:RequestTag/key2": "value2"
                },
                "ForAllValues:StringEquals": {
                    "aws:TagKeys": [
                        "key1",
                        "key2"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AllowCreateTagsOnlyLaunching",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:CreateTags"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:volume/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:instance/*"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "ec2:CreateAction": "RunInstances"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```